# Convert MS Word texts to plain valid html/css

Tags: html, css, ms-word, converters

I'm looking for a way to convert few paragraphs and ordered/unordered lists from a MS Word file to HTML.

Now, the problem is that when saving the Word file as a "htm/html" type of file (I'm using Word 2010), I get **tons** of all kinds of unwanted CSS directives, some are MS-invented and some are valid CSS, that I don't want in my html code. Moreover, and even more problematic, the ordered/unordered lists not even encoded to OL and UL with LI items, rather to a crazy Microsofty encoding.

For example, a paragraph (Styled as "Normal" in Word) is converted to:

```
<p class=MsoNormal>
 <span style='font-size:10.0pt;line-height:115%;mso-bidi-font-style:italic'>
  bla bla </span></p>
```

And I just want it to plainly be:

```
<p><span>bla bla</span></p>
```

More horrific, a simple unoredered list ("bulleted list") with one list item with is converted to:

```
<p class=MsoListParagraph style='text-indent:-18.0pt;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'>
 <![if !supportLists]>
  <span style='font-family:Symbol;mso-fareast-font-family:Symbol;mso-bidi-font-family:Symbol'>
   <span style='mso-list:Ignore'>·
    <span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    </span></span></span><![endif]>
 <span dir=LTR</span>Bla bla</p>
```

While I wish to get:

```
<ul><li>Bla bla</li></ul>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks so much!

p.s. I'm using Zend Studio (maybe there's a built in eclipse/zend-specific converter or something?)
p.s.p. The only MS Word options for exporting as html I've found are in Options => Advanced => General => Web Options. Playing with these options didn't solve any of the above problems.

Comment: Copy the code and then paste it in a plain text editor like Sublime Text 2.

Comment: @olwez Thanks, I'll try Sublime anyway (Though I see that it will require a paid license in the future) but I just figured out a simple solution, I'll write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, found a bizarre but working solution:

Use http://htmleditor.in/index.html and the "Paste from Word" option, **BUT** do this using (Ironically!) Internet Explorer (Tested with IE 9).

The reason is, when I used Chrome for the job, upon pressing "Paste from Word", an **html div-type pop up** came asking my permission to directly access my clipboard data, and when pasting there using ctrl-v the text, as required, the result was lacking the bullets (the bulleted items were converted to paragraphs).

On the contrary, when I used IE 9, instead of the div-type pop up, I get a **IE system-type pop up**, and pasting there keeps the bullets...

The irony here is that to solve a problem that started with Microsoft, I used another Microsoft product, where probably because of its poor html compatibility, did exactly what i wanted... lol.