# How do I convert a large document containing lists authored in word to clean html?

Tags: html, ms-word, date-conversion

Need a way to convert Microsoft word built in lists (ordered and unordered) to clean html UL or OL.

Comment: What you have tried? This is not code-for-me website.

Comment: I always use MS Word's global replace, along with ^p (for paragraphs) and ^t (for tabs).  You select the section that makes up the list, then figure out a way to replace all its paragraphs (^p) with the correct HTML tags.  For ordered lists, you'll probably need to cut that from Word and "Past Special" with no formatting; that replaces the numbered lists with text and keeps the item numbers that Word assigned. (Note that for lists with multiple levels, you'll probably need to code a converter in VBA.)

Comment: regex. write a regex statement that looks for the bullet point (or number followed by a period) then replace it by surrounding it by your ul/ol structure

Answer (score 1):

You can use a searchengine and find the following

- http://word2cleanhtml.com
- http://www.wordhtmlcleaner.co.uk
- http://www.ehow.com/how_8378449_automatically-word-list-html-list.html

Possible duplicate: [Convert MS Word texts to plain valid html/css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844506/convert-ms-word-texts-to-plain-valid-html-css)

Comment: yea, I was going to post the first site in your list as an answer to this question too.  I just used word2cleanhtml.com for my company's tandc doc and it was very helpful.  However it's worth going through any href links afterwards to make sure they go where you want them to.... some of these freebie converters throw their own urls in there (at least it seems that way in my experience).